# Flyway schema migration fails with DML and DDL script

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE with Flyway.

Flyway fails to perform the DML script when performing the schema migration.

My resources folder has the following structure for Flyway :

[image]

Performing Flyway on an empty database, works fine. It creates the schema and the data for the database.

But once, schema migration ( that is, changes in DML and DDL scripts) should be executed, Flyway shows the following error message :

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema `testDB` contains a failed migration to version 1.02 !
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:196) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1059) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
```

My **application-dev.properties** looks like this:

```
flyway.enabled=true
flyway.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
flyway.user: usertest
flyway.password: testtest
flyway.schemas=testDB
flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
flyway.locations:classpath:/db/migration/dev,/db/data

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy= org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.jpa.generate-ddl = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =none
```

Comment: It says there is a failed migration. There should be some error when performing on an empty database. Could you post them?

Comment: I think I found out why Flyway fails :  it cannot delete the previous entries in the database ! How can Flyway configured so it will delete old entries prior to inserting new data ?

Comment: You just write statements in a sql file like `delete from my_table where ...`

Comment: That's not an option. I solved it by using a Spring Bean and invoking the clean method of the Flyway class.

Answer (score 0):

That exception simply means that among the set of the "new" migrations identified by flyway on migrate execution, one or more scripts resulted in an error.

Flyway creates a table where it keeps track of the executed migration scripts along with their checksum, you can verify that table, it should contain one or more "0" in the execution result column.

When you are in this situation (on the local up to the dev stage) you could still simply delete the unsuccessful lines in the migration table, correct the incriminated scripts and finally, launch again the flyway migration.